# How to display user display name from Fireabase after login with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating simple web pages. A user should login with google account. Than he should be redirected to a page where welcome message is displayed with his name or email and a google map. Login is possible but I cant display the credientials. What could be the problem? The following code is located in the loggedin page- the one that displays after login. But it does not appear any welcome message.

```
<script>

 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
 if (user) {
 document.body.innerHTML='<h1>Welcome'+user.email+'</h1>';
 } else {
 console.log("no");
 }
```

I am using localhost to display the pages.What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend creating a users object and add user id to the user.

use user.uid and query firebase

```
function lookupUser(userId) {
      return $firebaseObject(getRoot().child("users").child(userId))
        .$loaded();
    }
```